# Different definitions of a sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, category-theory, sheaf-theory

In [SHEAVES, COSHEAVES AND APPLICATIONS](https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.3255), the author introduced a different definition for sheaves. Namely,

**Definition**: X is a topological space and $\mathcal{D}$ is a category, e.g. $\mathbf{Sets}$, $\mathbf{Vect}$, e.t.c.. Suppose $\mathcal{F}:\mathbf{Open}(X)^{op}\rightarrow \mathcal{D}$ is a presheaf, $\mathcal{U}=\{U_i\}$ is an open cover of a open set $U\subset X$, we say that $\mathcal{F}$ is a sheaf on $U$ if the unique map from $\mathcal{F}(U)$ to the limit of $\mathcal{F}\circ \iota^{op}_\mathcal{U}$ is an isomorphism. Here $\iota_\mathcal{U}$ is the canonical functor from nerve $\mathcal{N}(\mathcal{U})$ to $\mathbf{Open}(X)$.

In section 2.2, the author left an exercise to prove this definition is equivalent to the sheaf axioms of locality and gluing (see [Sheaf (mathematics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_(mathematics))). He implies that we should utilize a structure theorem in category theory: limits can be expressed by products and equalizers (Theorem 2.2.1).

However, I haven’t made any progress following this idea. The author said that “ Limit or colimit over the nerve of a cover can be determined after considering only the elements of the cover and their pairwise intersections. Do this by observing that the limit or colimit over the 1-skeleton of the nerve defines a cone or cocone over the whole nerve and employing universal properties.” To start with, is it possible to prove $\prod \mathcal{F}(U_i)\cong \prod \mathcal{F}(U_I)$, where $I$ corresponds to all objects in $\mathcal{N}(\mathcal{U})$?

Comment: what is your definition of nerve and open(X). key words to look for are descent and sheaves probably.